# Find number of platters of a given disk

Tags: computer-architecture

I am kinda blocked trying to figure out the answer to this question. Mind helping?

A manufacture wishes to design a hard disk with a capacity of 60 GB or more (using the standard definition of 1GB = 230 bytes). If the technology used to manufacture the disks allows 512-bytes sectors, 1024 sector/track, and 60% tracks/ platter, how many platters are required?

Comment: This seems like basic maths, not computer science. "Standard definition of 1GB = 230 bytes" is nonsense, and the standard definition is 1GB = 1 billion bytes.

Comment: cool, basic I get, but that does not even answer the question.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  If you understand the concepts, you should be able to figure out the answer through straightforward arithmetic.  If you don't understand the concepts, please ask a question about the concepts, in a way that will be helpful even to others who aren't doing exactly the same exercise-style task.

Comment: Giv-Mash What is 60% tracks/platter supposed to mean? And since when is the number of sectors per track constant?

Comment: (I'm not convinced the majority of hard disks manufactured this millennium had more than two tracks per platter: one spiral per surface. Or individually overwritable 512-bytes sectors at the recording level.)

Comment: gnasher Exactly my point, that is why I wanted help, because I did not understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

As per the given question,

Capacity of hard disk =60GB=60GB

1GB=2^{30}=10737418241GB=2
30
=1073741824 bytes

Number of bytes per sector =512=512 bytes/sector

Number of sector per track =1024=1024 sector /track

Number of track per platter =60%=60% tracks /platter

The capacity of one platter =512\times 1024\times \frac{60}{100}=314572.8=512×1024×
100
60
​
=314572.8  bytes/platter

Hence,capacity of one platter in GB =\frac{314572.8}{1073741824}=0.0002929GB=
1073741824
314572.8
​
=0.0002929GB

Hence, number of required platter to make 60GB hard disk =\frac{60}{0.0002929}=204848.0=
0.0002929
60
​
=204848.0

Comment: \frac denotes a fraction involving the values within the parenthesis. The first one being the numerator.

Comment: Use `$\frac x y$` to write $\frac xy$ and `$x \times y$` to write $x \times y$ (or `$x \cdot y$` to write $x \cdot y$): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What [form factor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_drive_form_factors) do you suggest? (Have a glimpse at the *Capacity
per platter* column.)